# Truncate catalina.out without tomcat restart

Tags: linux, bash, tomcat, cron

I am truncating catalina.out files via a bash script being executed as a cron job. Here is the code

```
# delete catalina.out files larger than 1 GiG, and replace with empty file if deleted

for f in $(find /tomcat_home*/. -name catalina.out -size +1000M); do
   rm $f
   touch $f
done
```

Nominally this works as written. The problem is that the running tomcat instance apparently cannot log to this newly created catalina.out (size always 0 bytes after creating), which renders my cron job kind of useless.

Basically, I need a solution that shrinks the file and but allows the running tomcat instance to keep writing to it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just use:

```
for f in $(find /tomcat_home*/. -name catalina.out -size +1000M); do
   echo "" >$f
done
```

The > sends the output in a fashion where it overwrites all the content (verses >> which appends). In this case you're never deleting the file, so you should be good.

Comment: that worked! truncates and tomcat is still writing to it. Thanks!